# Unity Lens Google Chrome Icon Will Not Go Away

Tags: unity, 14.04, google-chrome, icons, lenses

I was watching a youtube video, and quit chrome. For some reason, chrome saved itself as the youtube video name as in instead of Google Chrome, it is saved on the unity lens as "Three Main reasons War Is Going Away Youtube-Google Chrome" and I have tried to get rid of the Icon by updating chrome, updating ubuntu, and uninstalling chrome, but the icon stays there. I cannot open chrome, since it is obviously not installed anymore, but the icon is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings, Choose Privacy (Security and Privacy in 14.04), There you can delete history as well as turn off maintaining history for certain items. In 14.04 this is under the Files and Applications tab